# Avoid using CallbackHandler with cxf ws-security and spring

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security

I am in a spring bean defined with @Component.
I already have userName and password variables injected with @Value annotation from a property file.
I am calling a webservice using cfx autogenerated java code.
Unfortunately this webservice now uses ws-security and so I have to provide the password using a CallbackHandler.
Now cxf calls this java class directly without using spring and so how can I provide the right password to that class???
Why I can provide only userName directly and I have to use a callback handler to provide password?
Why webservices are always so bloody overengineered?
Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use `passwordCallbackRef` instead of `passwordCallbackClass`, inject password into `passwordCallbackRef` as showing below.

```
    <bean id="cpCallbackInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                <entry key="user" value="user" />
                <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>passwordCallbackRef</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="clientPasswordCallback" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


    <bean id="clientPasswordCallback " name="clientPasswordCallback " class="your.package.ClientPasswordCallback">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="${password}"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: <bean id="cpCallbackInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
  <constructor-arg>
   <map>
    <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
    <entry key="user" value="user" />
    <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
    <entry>
                        <key>
                            <value>passwordCallbackRef</value>
                        </key>
                        <ref bean="clientPasswordCallback" />
                </entry>
   </map>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler class:

```
public class ClientPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {
    private static String user = null;
    private static String password = null;

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

        if (user == null) {
            // Retrieve here your values
        }

        pc.setIdentifier(user);
        pc.setPassword(password);
    }
}
```

Assign this class to the WSS4JOutInterceptor. I have this defined on a xml:

```
<bean id="wss4jOut" class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
            <entry key="user" value="ws-client" />
            <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
            <entry key="passwordCallbackClass"
                value="your.package.ClientPasswordCallback" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```